# Remove INSPIRE themes button from home page and set new default

Tags: geonetwork, configuration

I am setting up a new catalog (GeoNetwork 4.2.4, installed using WAR) and would like to remove INSPIRE themes from the Browse by section of the home page and set the default Browse by category to be Topic.

I have not enabled INSPIRE in the System settings in Admin console > Settings. In addition, I have not configured any aspect of INSPIRE (I do not need it), yet INSPIRE themes is on the home page and it is the default Browse by option.

Once I am able to prevent INSPIRE themes from displaying in the Browse by section, I will also need to set the default to display themes by topic.

Besides the System settings, I have also gone through the User interface options on the Admin console and have not found a setting to configure the default Browse by option.

In perusing the settings, I also looked at the Facets configurations for the Home page and Search application, but as they do not include comments, I do know know if the changes I want to make can be made there. The documentation links included with the facet configurations did not really clear things up for me.

If I have misunderstood another configuration option, please let me know which one(s) to update to make these changes. If there is not a way to do it through the existing configuration forms, does anyone know what JavaScript and/or config file(s) I need to update to make the desired changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the INSPIRE themes button from the front page and set Browse by themes to topic, go to Admin console > Settings > User interface.

Using the Configuration form, scroll to the Home page section. In the Facets configuration box, delete the following:

```
"th_httpinspireeceuropaeutheme-theme_tree.key": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "th_httpinspireeceuropaeutheme-theme_tree.key",
        "size": 34
      },
      "meta": {
        "decorator": {
          "type": "icon",
          "prefix": "fa fa-2x pull-left gn-icon iti-",
          "expression": "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/theme/(.*)"
        }
      }
    },
```

Then select Save settings and refresh the catalog home page. The INSPIRE button is now gone and Topic is now the only Browse by option and the topic themes are displayed.

The same instructions apply when modifying the configuration using the JSON form. The main difference is the sections are not clearly separated by bars with titles in bold. The JSON form is organized with the same progression as the Configuration form so the Home page section will appear in the same location in each. However, when using the JSON form, the line to look for is:
"home": {